# Use openpyxl to save results to excel spreadsheet

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, openpyxl

I'm trying to use openpyxl to get some output in excel and am not getting anything.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone shed some light here.  Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# will give a list of all tickers
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 

# will give a list of all close values
close_values = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class = 'tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--numeric']/span")

for index in range(len(tickers)):


    fname = 'testresult.xlsx'
    if (os.path.exists(fname)):
              workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
              worksheet - workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
    else:
        workbook = Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
    worksheet.cell(row=1,column=2).value = tickers
    workbook.save(fname)
```

Comment: In your if statement, you have - instead of = on the second line.

Comment: Thanks, see below if you can help further.

Comment: You probably don't want to open and save the workbook for every element in your ticker.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement looks off, change to

```
fname = 'testresult.xlsx'
    if (os.path.exists(fname)):
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
        worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
    else:
        workbook = Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
```

Secondly, make sure you actually have something at 'tickers'. If you want to test that your logic is correct, first try:

```
worksheet.cell(row=1,column=2).value = 'hello world'
workbook.save(fname)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried replacing row=1 with row=index but then I didn't know what to put for column=????    Trying to get the list of tickers to print out.  Anyone??